# Oracle update value of a table using inner join with the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I am trying to update the depth column of bplustree table using this statement,which works fine on MYSQL,but on oracle I have this error:

```
BEGIN    
  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM bplustree WHERE depth IS NULL) 
  LOOP    
    UPDATE T SET T.depth = P.depth + 1
        FROM bplustree AS T INNER JOIN bplustree AS P 
        ON (T.parent_node_id = P.node_id) 
    WHERE P.depth >= 0 AND T.depth IS NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

> Error report -
>   ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   ORA-06550: line 3, column 2:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: Oracle does not support a `FROM` clause in `UPDATE`, so I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to calculate depth for each node in tree by putting a loop to run through all nodes of the tree @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine `update` and `select` by the help of `merge` like the following statement :

```
MERGE INTO bplustree t1
USING
(
  SELECT P.depth + 1 depth, p.node_id
    FROM bplustree T INNER JOIN bplustree P
      ON (T.parent_node_id = P.node_id)    
    WHERE P.depth >= 0 AND T.depth IS NULL 
) t2
ON ( t1.node_id = t2.node_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
t1.depth = t2.depth;
```

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33ff5/2)